# Recursive jquery ajax requests in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angular, ionic-framework

```
makeRequest(where, data, type?) {
    if (!type) {
        type = 'GET';
    }       
    $.ajax({
        method: type,
        url: baseaseUrl+where,
        data: data,
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log('ajax: ', msg);
            return msg;
        },
        error: function (a, b, data) {
            console.log(b + ' ' + data);
        },
        statusCode: {
            418: function(status) {
                console.log('418: ', status.status);
                return makeRequest(where, different_data);
            }                           
        }
    });             
}
```

This code is an excerpt from an ionic framework project. I want to make another request inside of an ajax request if the first (initial) request returns a certain (ex. 418) http status code. When I call "makeRequest()" it returns a 418 status code, which is okay, and then when I make the second request with different data I get:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (vendor.js:1)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
  at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:250)
```